# 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'sort'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I face some problem here, in my python package I have install `numpy`, but I still have this error:

> **'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'sort'**

Anyone can give me some idea..

This is my code :

```
final.loc[-1] =['', 'P','Actual']
final.index = final.index + 1  # shifting index
final = final.sort()
final.columns=[final.columns,final.iloc[0]]
final = final.iloc[1:].reset_index(drop=True)
final.columns.names = (None, None)
```

Answer (score 280, accepted):

`sort()` was deprecated for DataFrames in favor of either:

- [`sort_values()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) to **sort by column(s)**
- [`sort_index()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) to **sort by the index**

`sort()` was  deprecated (but still available) in Pandas with release 0.17 (2015-10-09) with the introduction of `sort_values()` and `sort_index()`. It was removed from Pandas with release 0.20 (2017-05-05).

Comment: What was the default behaviour of the old sort? That would be helpful for knowing which of the new versions should be used instead. The old docs seem a bit hopeless on this, e.g. they don't even say what happens when the default argument columns=None is used.

Answer (score 27):

## Pandas Sorting 101

`sort` has been replaced in v0.20 by [**`DataFrame.sort_values`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and [**`DataFrame.sort_index`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html). Aside from this, we also have `argsort`.

Here are some common use cases in sorting, and how to solve them using the sorting functions in the current API. First, the setup.

```
# Setup
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': list('accab'), 'B': np.random.choice(10, 5)})    
df                                                                                                                                        
   A  B
0  a  7
1  c  9
2  c  3
3  a  5
4  b  2
```

#### **Sort by Single Column**

For example, to sort `df` by column "A", use `sort_values` with a single column name:

```
df.sort_values(by='A')

   A  B
0  a  7
3  a  5
4  b  2
1  c  9
2  c  3
```

If you need a fresh RangeIndex, use [`DataFrame.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html).

#### **Sort by Multiple Columns**

For example, to sort by *both* col "A" and "B" in `df`, you can pass a list to `sort_values`:

```
df.sort_values(by=['A', 'B'])

   A  B
3  a  5
0  a  7
4  b  2
2  c  3
1  c  9
```

#### **Sort By DataFrame Index**

```
df2 = df.sample(frac=1)
df2

   A  B
1  c  9
0  a  7
2  c  3
3  a  5
4  b  2
```

You can do this using `sort_index`:

```
df2.sort_index()

   A  B
0  a  7
1  c  9
2  c  3
3  a  5
4  b  2

df.equals(df2)                                                                                                                            
# False
df.equals(df2.sort_index())                                                                                                               
# True
```

Here are some comparable methods with their performance:

```
%timeit df2.sort_index()                                                                                                                  
%timeit df2.iloc[df2.index.argsort()]                                                                                                     
%timeit df2.reindex(np.sort(df2.index))                                                                                                   

605 µs ± 13.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
610 µs ± 24.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
581 µs ± 7.63 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

#### **Sort by List of Indices**

For example,

```
idx = df2.index.argsort()
idx
# array([0, 7, 2, 3, 9, 4, 5, 6, 8, 1])
```

This "sorting" problem is actually a simple indexing problem. Just passing integer labels to `iloc` will do.

```
df.iloc[idx]

   A  B
1  c  9
0  a  7
2  c  3
3  a  5
4  b  2
```